# If exists is not printing pseudo values in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using a simple `if exists` statement in my stored procedure, but in output it is not printing the pseudo column values if the records does not exist.

SQL Server 2012

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1
    @Empid NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM employees WHERE id = @Empid)
    BEGIN
        SELECT id, name, salary, 'Newemp' AS status, 1 AS Code 
        FROM employees
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM employees WHERE id = @Empid)
    BEGIN
        SELECT id, name, salary, 'Oldemp' AS status1, 0 AS Code1 
        FROM employees
    END
END
```

Result:

If record exists, this is returned as expected

```
ID  Name Salary Status Code
-------------------------------
123 kkr  1000   Newemp  1
```

If the record doesn't exist - this is the problem:

```
Id Name Salary Status1 Code1 
-----------------------------
```

Desired value:

```
ID Name Salary Status1 Code1
----------------------------
               Oldemp  0
```

If the records doesn't exist, it is not printing the pseudo column values. I have changed the column names and executed to make sure that its taking the correct columns, and yes it is taking the correct ones, but failing to print the values.

Please help!

Comment: Try `select NULL as id, NULL AS name, NULL salary, 'Oldemp' as status1, 0 as Code1;` with no FROM clause to return a single row result set with only literals. My may also need to cast the `NULL` literal to the desired type if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself, but Big thanks for your answers.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1
@Empid NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
Create #temp
(Id Nvarchar(100),
 Name Nvarchar(100),
Salary Nvarchar(100),
Status Nvarchar(100),
Code Nvarchar(100)
)

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM employees WHERE id = @Empid)
BEGIN
 insert into #temp (id, name, salary)
   values  (SELECT id, name, salary 
    FROM employees  WHERE id = @Empid)
Insert into # temp (Status , Code)
           ('Newemp', 1)
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM employees WHERE id = @Empid)
BEGIN
    insert into #temp (id, name, salary)
   values  (SELECT id, name, salary 
    FROM employees  WHERE id = @Empid)
Insert into # temp (Status , Code)
           ('Oldemp', 0)
END

Select * from #temp
END
```

Answer (score 0):

These queries are based on the number of records in `employees` - it could be one, it could be none, and it could be many. If you always want to get a single row, you can omit the `from` clause and just select literals:

```
SELECT NULL AS id, NULL AS name, NULL AS salary, 'Oldemp' ASs status1, 0 AS Code1
```

Comment: yup i am selecting only 1 query using max(date) in my original query. But, still I am not getting the desired result. It is working for IF Exist, I do not why its failing to give result for IF Not Exist.